# Short way to replace values in a Series based on values in another Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I the below code, I am replacing all `NaN` values from column `b` with blank string if the corresponding value in column `a` is 1.

The code works, but I have to type `df.loc[df.a == 1, 'b']` twice.

Is there a shorter/better way to do it?

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [1, None, 3],
        'b': [None, 5, 6],
    })

    filtered = df.loc[df.a == 1, 'b']
    filtered.fillna('', inplace=True)
    df.loc[df.a == 1, 'b'] = filtered
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) only for matched values by condition:

```
df.loc[df.a == 1, 'b'] = df['b'].fillna('')
```

Comment: Hello from [Low Quality Posts Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23137517) :)

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks, it works. Do you mind to explain how is that possible, since `df.loc[df.a == 1, 'b']` and `df['b']` have different lengths: 1 vs 3?

Comment: @barciewicz - I think it working like assign all values from `df['b'].fillna('')` but only for filtered values of column `df['b']`

Answer (score 1):

how about the use of numpy `where` clause to check values in a and b and replace? see a mockup below. I have used column '`c`' to illustrate

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [1, None, 3],
        'b': [None, 5, 6],
    })
#replace b value if the corresponding value in column a is 1 and column b is NaN
df['c'] = np.where(((df['a'] == 1) & (df['b'].isna())), df['a'], df['b'])
df
```

original dataframe

```
     a  b
0   1.0 1.0
1   NaN 5.0
2   3.0 6.0
```

result:

```
      a b   c
0   1.0 NaN 1.0
1   NaN 5.0 5.0
2   3.0 6.0 6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use where() to do it in one line

```
import numpy as np
```

`df['b'] = np.where((df['b'].isnull()) & (df['a']==1),'',df['a'])`